# DocumentList API FullTextQuery ServiceException - An unknown error has occured

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

For some queries I receive this ServiceException after 10 seconds of 
waiting for the response.

I also tried with direct http get request and the same result.

Ex: Contract%20Colectiv%20de%20Munc%C4%83

```
1. My code: 

    URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/ full/folder%3A" + folderId + "/contents/-/pdf");                        
    DocumentQuery query = new DocumentQuery(feedUrl); 
    query.setFullTextQuery(searchText); 
    client.setConnectTimeout(0);// with or without this line I receive the same result (I also put 30000 value - same result) 
    client.setReadTimeout(0);// with or without this line I receive the same result 

    DocumentListFeed feed = client.getFeed(query, DocumentListFeed.class); 


2. This is the stacktrace for the exception that I receive with documentlist api query: 

    com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException: An unknown error has occurred. 
    <errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
    <error><domain>GData</domain><code>ServiceException</code>
    <internalReason>An unknown error has occurred</internalReason>
    </error></errors> 
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:624)
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:563) 
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java: 552) 
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java: 530) 
    at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:535) 
    at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135) 
    ... 

3. This is the exception I receive with direct http get request: 

     java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3[my_folder_doc-id]/contents/-/pdf?q="[query_text]"&max-results=25 
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java: 1436) 
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java: 379) 
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java: 318) 
    at GoogleDocsManager.googleSearch(GoogleDocsManager.java:281)
```

Additional information:

```
1. My folder contains almost 300k files. Could this be the problem? 
2. In ~85% of searches I get the correct response () 
3. In browser the same interogation returns "The server encountered an error. Please try again later", but after refresh works fine.
```

Can anyone help me to get a "workaround" for this problem? Or how to 
avoid it?

I posted this issue some months ago on [documentlist api group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!searchin/google-documents-list-api/andrei.fifiita/google-documents-list-api/-Z16CcE7pnA/ROHuFMJhOKoJ) but since this group is read-only I can't get any information about this issue.

---

This is the 500 response I get with direct http request (after ~10 seconds):

```
<errors xmlns='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'>
    <error>
        <domain>GData</domain>
        <code>ServiceException</code>
        <internalReason>An unknown error has occurred.</internalReason>
    </error>
</errors>
```

This is the code:

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3A" +  folderId + "/contents/-/pdf?max-results=25&q=" + searchText);                        

HttpURLConnection copyHttpUrlConn = (HttpURLConnection) feedUrl.openConnection(); 
copyHttpUrlConn.setDoOutput(true); 
copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestMethod("GET");            
copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("GData-Version", "3.0");
copyHttpUrlConn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + authToken);
int respCode = copyHttpUrlConn.getResponseCode(); 

System.out.println("Response  code: " + respCode);

InputStreamReader isr = null;
if(respCode != 200){
    isr = new InputStreamReader(copyHttpUrlConn.getErrorStream());
}
else{
    isr = new InputStreamReader(copyHttpUrlConn.getInputStream());
}
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr); 

String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(line); 
}
```

Other recent queries with problems:

1. title:2012-05 "exceptii de neconstitutionalitate penal"
2. "litigii de munca"
3. "moş crăciun srl"
4. "bil terenuri sa bucuresti"
5. "ordonanta de plata"

Comment: Have you tried printing out the body of the 500 response you get with a direct request? That probably tells you more about the problem. Also, you seriously have 300,000 documents in Google Docs?!

Comment: Hi Nick,
Yes, I have ~300k (96 GB) files, 95% of them are small pdf files. Could this be a problem? 
(*) I will write the 500 response as a reply to my question.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can consider fetching the large document list offline using a task queue, and serializing the information you want to display in the datastore.

Using task queue will give you give you automatic retry if there is an error, and up to 10 minutes deadline for the urlfetch and processing deadline.

Comment: In the api, it doesn't mather how many retries I make, I receive the same 500 response. My problem is that I can't get the results and that because the query fails after 10 seconds.